# Converting PHP script that uses OCI to use PDO

Tags: php, oop, pdo, datatables, oracle-call-interface

I have been using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) with the below PHP script that uses OCI however since I re-wrote the whole site to utilize PDO I now need to update this PHP script to also utilize PDO.

The problem is that there are no error messages reported (I have error reporting enabled) but the DataTable is empty.

Is there a noticeable mistake in how I converted it to utilize PDO?

### OCI - works!

```
// Database connection information
$sql = array(
    'user'     => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'server'   => '192.168.0.1',
    'db'       => 'A.world'
);

// Oracle connection
$conn = oci_connect($sql['user'], $sql['password'], $sql['server'].'/'.$sql['db']);//$connection_string);

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error( htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR );
}


// Action
$out = dt_oci_ssp( $conn, $query, $_POST );

echo json_encode( $out );



/**
 * DataTables 1.10+ server-side processing function for Oracle using oci_*
 * methods
 * @param  resource $conn  Connection from `oci_connect`
 * @param  array $query    Information for the query to be performed
 * @param  array $data     Data from the server-side processing request
 * @return array           Data returned for server-side processing
 */
function dt_oci_ssp( $conn, $query, $data ) {
    $bindings = array();

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $orderBy = array();

    if ( isset( $data['order'] ) ) {
        for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['order'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
            $sort = $data['order'][$i];

            //Add to the order by clause
            $orderBy[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $sort['column'] ) .' '. (
                $sort['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                    'asc' :
                    'desc'
                );
        }
    }

    $orderBy = count( $orderBy ) ?
        'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy) :
        '';


    // Conditions
    $where = array();
    $whereJoinOnly = array();

    $globalWhere = array();

    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['columns'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $column = $data['columns'][$i];

        if ( $column['searchable'] && $data['search']['value'] ) {
            $bindings[':globalSearch'.$i] = '%'.$data['search']['value'].'%';
            $globalWhere[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i ) ." LIKE :globalSearch".$i;
        }
    }

    if ( count( $globalWhere ) ) {
        $where[] .= '('.implode(' OR ', $globalWhere).')';
    }


    // Column filter
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['columns'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $column = $data['columns'][$i];

        if ( $column['searchable'] && $column['search']['value'] ) {
            $bindings[':columnSearch'.$i] = '%'.$column['search']['value'].'%';
            $where[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i ) ." LIKE :columnSearch".$i;
        }
    }


    // Joins
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $query['conditions'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $where[] = $query['conditions'][$i];
        $whereJoinOnly[] = $query['conditions'][$i];
    }

    $where = count( $where ) ?
        'WHERE '.implode( ' AND ', $where ) :
        '';

    $whereJoinOnly = count( $whereJoinOnly ) ?
        'WHERE '.implode( ' AND ', $whereJoinOnly ) :
        '';


    $tables = implode( ', ', $query['tables'] );

    $select = array();
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $query['fields'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $select[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i, 'select' ) .' as "'. dt_oci_field( $query, $i ).'"'; 
    }

    $select = implode( ', ', $select );


    $betweenLower = intval($data['start']);
    $betweenUpper = intval($data['start'] + $data['length']);

    if ( $data['length'] != -1 ) {
        $dataOut = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
            SELECT a.*
            FROM (
                SELECT rownum rnum, b.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM $tables
                    $where
                    $orderBy
                ) b
                WHERE rownum <= $betweenUpper
            ) a
            WHERE rnum > $betweenLower
EOD
        );
    }
    else {
        // All records
        $dataOut = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
            SELECT a.*
            FROM (
                SELECT rownum rnum, b.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM $tables
                    $where
                    $orderBy
                ) b
            ) a
EOD
        );
    }

    $filterCount = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $where
        $orderBy
EOD
    );

    $fullCount = dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $whereJoinOnly
EOD
    );


    // Output
    $out = array(
        'draw'            => intval( $data['draw'] ),
        'data'            => array(),
        'recordsFiltered' => intval($filterCount['COUNT'][0]),
        'recordsTotal'    => intval($fullCount['COUNT'][0])
    );

    for ( $i=0, $ien=count($dataOut['RNUM']) ; $i<$ien ; ++$i ) {
        $row = array();

        for ( $j=0, $jen=count($data['columns']) ; $j<$jen ; ++$j ) {
            $row[] = $dataOut[ dt_oci_field( $query, $j ) ][$i];
        }

        $out['data'][] = $row;
    }

    return $out;
}


/**
 * Get a field property for a query
 * @param  array   $query Query information
 * @param  integer $idx   Field index
 * @param  string  $type  `name` or `select`
 * @return string         column name
 */
function dt_oci_field ( $query, $idx, $type='name' ) {
    if ( is_array( $query['fields'][$idx] ) ) {
        return $query['fields'][$idx][$type];
    }

    return $query['fields'][$idx];
}


/**
 * Perform a SQL command, returning the full result set
 * @param  resource $conn     Connection from `oci_connect`
 * @param  array    $bindings Binding information to use
 * @param  string   $query    SQL query
 * @return array              Results
 */
function dt_oci_exec( $conn, $bindings, $query )
{
    $stmt = oci_parse( $conn, trim($query) );

    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        if ( strpos( $query, $key) ) {
            oci_bind_by_name( $stmt, $key, $value );
        }
    }

    oci_execute( $stmt );
    oci_fetch_all( $stmt, $data );
    oci_free_statement( $stmt );

    return $data;
```

### PDO - doesn't work! No error messages, connection is ok but no data passed back to DataTables :<

```
// Oracle connection
$dbh = new PDO('oci:dbname=//192.168.0.1:1521/A.world', 'user', 'pass', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));


// Action
$out = dt_oci_ssp( $dbh, $query, $_POST );

echo json_encode( $out );



/**
 * DataTables 1.10+ server-side processing function for Oracle using oci_*
 * methods
 * @param  resource $dbh  Connection from `oci_connect`
 * @param  array $query    Information for the query to be performed
 * @param  array $data     Data from the server-side processing request
 * @return array           Data returned for server-side processing
 */
function dt_oci_ssp( $dbh, $query, $data ) {
    $bindings = array();

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $orderBy = array();

    if ( isset( $data['order'] ) ) {
        for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['order'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
            $sort = $data['order'][$i];

            //Add to the order by clause
            $orderBy[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $sort['column'] ) .' '. (
                $sort['dir'] === 'asc' ?
                    'asc' :
                    'desc'
                );
        }
    }

    $orderBy = count( $orderBy ) ?
        'ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $orderBy) :
        '';


    // Conditions
    $where = array();
    $whereJoinOnly = array();

    $globalWhere = array();

    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['columns'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $column = $data['columns'][$i];

        if ( $column['searchable'] && $data['search']['value'] ) {
            $bindings[':globalSearch'.$i] = '%'.$data['search']['value'].'%';
            $globalWhere[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i ) ." LIKE :globalSearch".$i;
        }
    }

    if ( count( $globalWhere ) ) {
        $where[] .= '('.implode(' OR ', $globalWhere).')';
    }


    // Column filter
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $data['columns'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $column = $data['columns'][$i];

        if ( $column['searchable'] && $column['search']['value'] ) {
            $bindings[':columnSearch'.$i] = '%'.$column['search']['value'].'%';
            $where[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i ) ." LIKE :columnSearch".$i;
        }
    }


    // Joins
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $query['conditions'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $where[] = $query['conditions'][$i];
        $whereJoinOnly[] = $query['conditions'][$i];
    }

    $where = count( $where ) ?
        'WHERE '.implode( ' AND ', $where ) :
        '';

    $whereJoinOnly = count( $whereJoinOnly ) ?
        'WHERE '.implode( ' AND ', $whereJoinOnly ) :
        '';


    $tables = implode( ', ', $query['tables'] );

    $select = array();
    for ( $i=0, $size=count( $query['fields'] ) ; $i<$size ; ++$i ) {
        $select[] = dt_oci_field( $query, $i, 'select' ) .' as "'. dt_oci_field( $query, $i ).'"'; 
    }

    $select = implode( ', ', $select );


    $betweenLower = intval($data['start']);
    $betweenUpper = intval($data['start'] + $data['length']);

    if ( $data['length'] != -1 ) {
        $dataOut = dt_oci_exec( $dbh, $bindings, <<<EOD
            SELECT a.*
            FROM (
                SELECT rownum rnum, b.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM $tables
                    $where
                    $orderBy
                ) b
                WHERE rownum <= $betweenUpper
            ) a
            WHERE rnum > $betweenLower
EOD
        );
    }
    else {
        // All records
        $dataOut = dt_oci_exec( $dbh, $bindings, <<<EOD
            SELECT a.*
            FROM (
                SELECT rownum rnum, b.*
                FROM (
                    SELECT $select
                    FROM $tables
                    $where
                    $orderBy
                ) b
            ) a
EOD
        );
    }

    $filterCount = dt_oci_exec( $dbh, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $where
        $orderBy
EOD
    );

    $fullCount = dt_oci_exec( $dbh, $bindings, <<<EOD
        SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT
        FROM $tables
        $whereJoinOnly
EOD
    );


    // Output
    $out = array(
        'draw'            => intval( $data['draw'] ),
        'data'            => array(),
        'recordsFiltered' => intval($filterCount['COUNT'][0]),
        'recordsTotal'    => intval($fullCount['COUNT'][0])
    );

    for ( $i=0, $ien=count($dataOut['RNUM']) ; $i<$ien ; ++$i ) {
        $row = array();

        for ( $j=0, $jen=count($data['columns']) ; $j<$jen ; ++$j ) {
            $row[] = $dataOut[ dt_oci_field( $query, $j ) ][$i];
        }

        $out['data'][] = $row;
    }

    return $out;
}


/**
 * Get a field property for a query
 * @param  array   $query Query information
 * @param  integer $idx   Field index
 * @param  string  $type  `name` or `select`
 * @return string         column name
 */
function dt_oci_field ( $query, $idx, $type='name' ) {
    if ( is_array( $query['fields'][$idx] ) ) {
        return $query['fields'][$idx][$type];
    }

    return $query['fields'][$idx];
}


/**
 * Perform a SQL command, returning the full result set
 * @param  resource $dbh      Connection from `oci_connect`
 * @param  array    $bindings Binding information to use
 * @param  string   $query    SQL query
 * @return array              Results
 */
function dt_oci_exec( $dbh, $bindings, $query )
{
 try {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

  foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
   if ( strpos( $query, $key) ) {
    $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value);
   }
  }

  $stmt->execute();
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $stmt = null;

  return $data;
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }
}
```

I have sat and looked at both code for a number of hours now and as far as I can tell I have converted it to use the correct PDO commands etc.

Comment: You need to install the PDO_OCI driver on your server . http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Comment: @Daan Hm? PDO works fine as I already said, my site is written in it. This question is concerning DataTables.

Comment: Can you show me the output of this code: `foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver)
    echo $driver, '\n';`

Comment: @Daan I already told you, PDO works fine, my site is written in it. `oci\nsqlite\n`.

Comment: Add this line below your connection string it might give you some information `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); ` And where are your try catches ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong quotes:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':$key', $value);
                 ^-----^--
```

`'`-quoted strings do not interpolate variable values, so you're binding a placeholder with the literal name `$`, `k`, `e`, etc... which doesn't exist in your query. So the bind fails, and since you have no error handling in your code, you never see the error messages PDO could be giving you.

**NEVER** assume success. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Try

```
$stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value);
                 ^-----^---
```

instead.

Comment: It would probably also work without the quotes, like so: `$stmt->bindParam($key, $value);`

Comment: Nope. still need the `:` in there. `bindParam('foo',...)` is wrong

Comment: I remember using it without the `:`, but maybe my memory is a bit off.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. I have changed to using ", and put it within a try catch block. The output sent to DataTables is still empty though, compared to when I use the OCI version above. Output: `{"draw":1,"data":[],"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0}`.

Comment: pdo doesn't throw exceptions by default. you have explicitly enable it. default behavior is to return boolean false on failure. Check [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: @MarcB I do it in the connection at the top.

Comment: Thanks anyway Marc B. I've looked at this for near enough 8 hours now and I'm at a loss as the connection etc. is working fine, it's just not returning data :-(